# How do I change my code so you can type in keywords?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code which when it's run - will have you pick 1 to 4. However, I would like to change it so I could just enter keywords instead. For example, it could say "What is wrong with your code" and I'd answer by saying "My screen is frozen" which would then take me to the screen frozen questions.

Thank you very much for any help, as I am really new to python and don't know much of the terminology. I would appreciate it if you could tell me where to put the added code or reply with it in the code.

```
def menu():
  print("Welcome to Kierans Phone Troubleshooting program")
  print("Please Enter your name")
  name=input()
  print("Thanks for using Kierans Phone Troubleshooting program "+name +"\n")

def start():
  select = " "
  print("Would you like to start this program? Please enter either y for yes or n for no")
  select=input()
  if select=="y":
    troubleshooter()
  elif select=="n":
    quit
  else:
    print("Invalid please enter again")

def troubleshooter():
  print("""Please choose the problem you are having with your phone (input 1-4):
1) My phone doesn't turn on
2) My phone is freezing
3) The screen is cracked
4) I dropped my phone in water\n""")
  problemselect = int(input())
  if problemselect ==1:
    not_on()
  elif problemselect ==2:
    freezing()
  elif problemselect ==3:
    cracked()
  elif problemselect ==4:
    water()
  start()

def not_on():
  print("Have you plugged in the charger?")
  answer = input()
  if answer =="y":
    print("Charge it with a diffrent charger in a diffrent phone socket. Does it work?")
  else:
    print("Plug it in and leave it for 20 mins, has it come on?")
  answer = input()
  if answer=="y":
    print("Are there any more problems?")
  else:
    print("Restart the troubleshooter or take phone to a specialist\n")
  answer=input()
  if answer =="y":
    print("Restart this program")
  else:
    print("Thank you for using my troubleshooting program!\n")

def freezing():
  print("Charge it with a diffrent charger in a diffrent phone socket")
  answer = input("Are there any more problems?")
  if answer=="y":
    print("Restart the troubleshooter or take phone to a specialist\n")
  else:
    print("Restart this program\n")

def cracked():
  answer =input("Is your device responsive to touch?")
  if answer=="y":
    answer2 = input("Are there any more problems?")
  else:
    print("Take your phone to get the screen replaced")
  if answer2=="y":
    print("Restart the program or take phone to a specialist\n")
  else:
    print("Thank you for using my troubleshooting program!\n")

def water():
  print("Do not charge it and take it to the nearest specialist\n")

menu()
while True:
  start()
  troubleshooter()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list which contains all of the possible problems. For example:

```
def troubleshooter():
    problems = ["My phone doesn't turn on",
                "My phone is freezing",
                "The screen is cracked",
                "I dropped my phone in water"]
    print("""Please choose the problem you are having with your phone (input 1-4):
1) My phone doesn't turn on
2) My phone is freezing
3) The screen is cracked
4) I dropped my phone in water\n""")
    problemselect = input()
    if problemselect == problems[0]:
        not_on()
    elif problemselect == problems[1]:
        freezing()
    elif problemselect == problems[2]:
        cracked()
    elif problemselect == problems[3]:
        water()
    start()
```

If you mean that you'd like to find a certain word, that can be accomplished by the following:

```
>>> sentence = "Hello World!"
>>> word = "Hello"
>>> if word in sentence:
    print("Yep!")

Yep!
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay maybe I got your question right:

You can use regular expressions to search for the keywords. But since you are new to python it is better to use `find()` as follows, I guess it's simple enough and accurate for your purpose but not fully robust:
Give it a try by just replacing `troubleshooter()` with the following function definition:

```
def troubleshooter():
    q = raw_input('Enter you problem : ')
    q = q.lower()
    freeze = ['freeze', 'froze', 'freezing', 'hang', 'hung'] #you can keep adding
    boot = ['turn on', 'boot', 'off'] #you can again keep adding
    screen = ['cracked', 'crack', 'broke', 'shattered', 'shatter'] #keep adding
    water = ['water', 'liquid']
    freeze_q = sum([q.find(keyword) for keyword in freeze])
    boot_q = sum([q.find(keyword) for keyword in boot])
    screen_q = sum([q.find(keyword) for keyword in screen])
    water_q = sum([q.find(keyword) for keyword in water])

    if freeze_q > -len(freeze):
        # print 'freeze problem'
        not_on()
    elif boot_q > -len(boot):
        # print 'boot problem'
        freezing()
    elif screen_q > -len(screen):
        # print 'screen problem'
        cracked()
    elif water_q > -len(water):
        # print 'water problem'
        water()
    else:
        print 'invalid question'
```

Making it robust is another topic which comes under NLP : http://www.nltk.org/
Accept the answer if it helped.